# How to filter my query in knex.js to get the lesser count and empty cell in a table?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I'm trying to use a knexjs query to to get an empty cell in a row and then if it returns multiple rows I select the lesser count of some value in each row.

which means i check each row for the "some value"

if i got 2 rows but first row has 4 cells of the "some value" and the second row has 2 cells of that value
I choose the second row.at the same time i keep in mind the empty cell as my condition.

I tried doing this

```
knexDb('test_table')          
  .where(function() {
    this.where('col1', '=', '')
    .orWhere('col2', '=', '')
    .orWhere('col3', '=', '')
    .orWhere('col4', '=', '')
    .orWhere('col5', '=', '')
  })
  .orderByRaw('random()')
  // here i get all the availabe rows with empty cells

  // then here i want to do some check to compare all rows with the lesser count of "some value"
```

Remember that i check each column in the row by doing col1, col2, col3, etc...

which means i need a reference to the return values and keep track of the count of that value that exists in each row.

===============================================

Updated

===============================================

test_table has 3 rows as follows:

```
{
    id: 1,
    col1: '',
    col2: '',
    col3: 'sasha',
},
{
    id: 2,
    col1: '',
    col2: 'sasha',
    col3: 'sasha',
},
{
    id: 3,
    col1: 'another_name',
    col2: 'another_name',
    col3: 'another_name',
}
```

the above query will return the first 2 objects because they have empty cell

now the desired output is to choose and return the first object as it has lesser count of (sasha) and has empty cell

Comment: What is the sql query that you are trying to build?

Comment: not sql query. i'm using knex.js with psql.

Comment: Yeah, i get it... What is the query u want to build with knex?

Comment: I want to search all rows for any empty cell with condition to check the lesser count of value i pass it. For example I have 2 rows both have empty cell the above query will return the 2 rows so after that i want to check the count of specific value (for example name) in each row and then choose the row that has the lesser count

Comment: I updated the question and gave an example to clarify the question @felixmosh

Answer (score 1):

Your question is divided into 2 parts:

1. How to query?

```sql
SELECT *, 
       ( SELECT 
           (CASE WHEN col1='sasha' THEN 1 ELSE 0 End) + 
           (CASE WHEN col2='sasha' THEN 1 ELSE 0 End) +
           (CASE WHEN col3='sasha' THEN 1 ELSE 0 End))
         FROM   test_table AS INNER 
         WHERE  inner.id = test_table.id
       ) AS counter 
FROM   test_table 
WHERE  col1 = '' 
        OR col2 = '' 
        OR col3 = '' 
ORDER  BY counter ASC 
LIMIT  1
```

2. How to build this SQL query in `knex`

```js
const columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'];

knexDb('test_table')
  .columns([
    '*',
    knexDb('test_table as inner')
      .column(
        knexDb.raw(
          '(' +
            columns.map((col) => `(CASE WHEN ${col}='sasha' THEN 1 ELSE 0 End)`).join(' + ') +
            ') as inner_counter'
        )
      )
      .where('inner.id', '=', 'test_table.id')
      .orderBy('inner_counter')
      .limit(1)
      .as('counter'),
  ])
  .where((qb) => {
    columns.forEach((col) => {
      qb.orWhere(col, '=', '');
    });
  })
  .orderByRaw('random()');
```

Comment: I'm getting this error

`error: column "(CASE WHEN mn0='sasha' THEN 1 ELSE 0) End + (CASE WHEN mn1='sasha" does not exist`

i changed the col1 to mn1 as in db

Comment: And if i run the query in `psql` query editor i get this error `ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 3:            (CASE WHEN mn0='sasha' THEN 1 ELSE 0) End + 
                                                       ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 76`

Comment: Yeah, my wrong, the `End` is part of the case, I've updated the answer

Comment: I'm still getting this error `error: column "(CASE WHEN mn0='sasha' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN mn1='sas" does not exist`

Comment: Correct, this is because we put an expression inside a column... we need to wrap it with `raw`, BTW, you can append `.debug` to your query and check how it was constructed